# Why this error trying to unit test an entire Spring Batch Job? No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.batch.core.Job' available

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, spring-batch

I am working on a Spring Batch application. Untill now I was able to unit test something like service methods and something like this (as done in every Spring Boot application).

Now I am trying to follow this tutorial in order to test an entire job from my unit test class (basically I want to execute a test method that perform a Job): https://www.baeldung.com/spring-batch-testing-job

This is my JUnit test class, in this case works fine and I correctly can test my services method using the **@SpringBootTest** annotation:

```
@SpringBootTest
@SpringBatchTest
class UpdateInfoBatchApplicationTests {
    
    @Autowired
    private NotaryService notaryService;
    
    @Autowired
    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;
  
    @Autowired
    private JobRepositoryTestUtils jobRepositoryTestUtils;
  
    @After
    public void cleanUp() {
    jobRepositoryTestUtils.removeJobExecutions();
    }
    
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("launcher")
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;
    
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("updateNotaryDistrictsJob")
    private Job updateNotaryDistrictsJob;
    
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("updateNotaryListInfoJob")
    private Job updateNotaryListInfoJob;
    
    private JobParameters defaultJobParameters() {
    JobParametersBuilder paramsBuilder = new JobParametersBuilder();
    //paramsBuilder.addString("file.input", TEST_INPUT);
    //paramsBuilder.addString("file.output", TEST_OUTPUT);
    return paramsBuilder.toJobParameters();
   }
    
    @Test
    public void givenReferenceOutput_whenJobExecuted_thenSuccess() throws Exception {
    // when
    JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob(defaultJobParameters());
    JobInstance actualJobInstance = jobExecution.getJobInstance();
    ExitStatus actualJobExitStatus = jobExecution.getExitStatus();
    
    Assert.assertEquals(actualJobInstance.getJobName(), "updateNotaryDistrictsJob");
      
    // then
    //assertThat(actualJobInstance.getJobName(), is("updateNotaryDistrictsJob"));
    //assertThat(actualJobExitStatus.getExitCode(), is("COMPLETED"));
    //AssertFile.assertFileEquals(expectedResult, actualResult);
    }

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
        System.out.println("TEST - contextLoads()");
    }
    
    @Test
    void getNotaryList() throws Exception {
    List<Notary> notaryList = this.notaryService.getNotaryList();
    System.out.println("notaryList size: " + notaryList);
    Assert.assertEquals("Notary List must be 5069", 5069, notaryList.size());
    }
    
    @Test
    void getNotaryDetails() throws Exception {
        NotaryDetails notaryDetails = this.notaryService.getNotaryDetails("089cy5Ra9zE%253D");
        System.out.println("notaryDetails: " + notaryDetails);
        Assert.assertEquals("Notary ID must be 089cy5Ra9zE%253D", "089cy5Ra9zE%253D", notaryDetails.getIdNotary());
    }
    
    @Test
    void getNotaryDistrictsList() throws Exception {
        List<NotaryDistrict> notaryDistrictsList = this.notaryService.getNotaryDistrictsList();
        System.out.println("notaryDistrictsList: " + notaryDistrictsList);
        
        Assert.assertEquals("Notary districts list lenght must be 91", 91, notaryDistrictsList.size());
        
        //ArrayList<NotaryDistrict>  notaryDistrictsListArrayList = new ArrayList<NotaryDistrict>(notaryDistrictsList);
        notaryDistrictsList.remove(0);
        Assert.assertEquals("Notary districts list lenght must now be 90", 90, notaryDistrictsList.size());
    }
    
    @Test
    void getNotaryDistrictDetails() throws Exception {
        NotaryDistrictDetails notaryDistrictDetails =  this.notaryService.getNotaryDistrictDetails("CG7drXn9fvA%253D");
        System.out.println("notaryDistrictDetails: " + notaryDistrictDetails.toString());
        
        Assert.assertEquals("Distretto must be: SCIACCA", "SCIACCA", notaryDistrictDetails.getDistretto());
    }
}
```

As you can see in the previous code I first inject my two Job objects defined:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("launcher")
private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("updateNotaryDistrictsJob")
private Job updateNotaryDistrictsJob;
```

These **Job** are defined as bean into the class that configures my Spring Batch jobs and steps, basically I have these 2 beans:

```
@Bean("updateNotaryDistrictsJob")
public Job updateNotaryDistrictsListInfoJob(){
    return jobs.get("updateNotaryDistrictsListInfoJob")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .start(readNotaryDistrictsListStep())
            .build();
}
```

and

```
@Bean("updateNotaryListInfoJob")
public Job updateNotaryListInfoJob(){
    return jobs.get("updateNotaryListInfoJob")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .start(readNotaryListStep())
            .build();
}
```

Then in the previous test class there is this test method that should test the entire flow of the previous **updateNotaryDistrictsJob** job:

```
@Test
public void givenReferenceOutput_whenJobExecuted_thenSuccess() throws Exception {
    // when
    JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob(defaultJobParameters());
    JobInstance actualJobInstance = jobExecution.getJobInstance();
    ExitStatus actualJobExitStatus = jobExecution.getExitStatus();
    
    Assert.assertEquals(actualJobInstance.getJobName(), "updateNotaryDistrictsJob");
}
```

The problem is that doing in this way when I run this test method I am obtaining this exception in my stack trace:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jobLauncherTestUtils': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setJob' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.batch.core.Job' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: updateNotaryDistrictsJob,updateNotaryListInfoJob
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:768) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:720) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1413) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:123) ~[spring-boot-test-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) ~[spring-test-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124) ~[spring-test-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    ... 69 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.batch.core.Job' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: updateNotaryDistrictsJob,updateNotaryListInfoJob
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveNotUnique(DependencyDescriptor.java:220) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1358) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    ... 88 common frames omitted
```

It seems that it can't recognize what of my two Job beans must be used.

Why? What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I try to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `JobLauncherTestUtils` that is provided by `@SpringBatchTest` expects that there is only a single bean of type `Job` in the test context. This is also documented in the java doc of the annotation.

If you use `@SpringBootTest` and full component scanning such that more than one job bean is picked up, `@SpringBatchTest` does not work out of the box.

The easiest solution is probably to remove `@SpringBatchTest` and to start the jobs with the `jobLauncher`. Alternatively, you can split your tests across multiple test classes and use test contexts that only contain a single job bean, respectively.

Comment: So do you mean to create another test class that itself is annotated only with SpringBatchTest annotation? In case I try the other way: I maintain only the SpringBootTest annotation on my test class and then how can I use the jobnLauncher to launch my job? Tnx

Comment: I would separate the tests of each job in a separate class, something like the example shown here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/3699#issuecomment-702966663. You would be able to autowire the `JobLauncherTestUtils` in each test class (thanks to `@SpringBatchTest`) with the job under test already set on it.